# Number of nodes satisfying a certain property on a binary tree

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

Fix a large integer $M$ and construct a binary tree as follows.

- Assign the root node by the integer $0$.
- If a node is assigned the integer $n$ and $n \leq M - 2$, then $n$
  has two children and one of the children is assigned the integer $n +
     1$ and the other is assigned $n + 2$.
- If a node is assigned the integer $n$ and $n = M - 1$ or $n = M$, then this node does not have any children.
- Repeat until the second rule cannot be applied (as in until none of the nodes can have any children since they are all assigned $M$ or $M - 1$).

So for an example if $M = 4$, the tree would look like

- First row: 0
- Second row: 1    2
- Third row:  2 3 3 4 (2 3 are children of 1 in 2nd row, 3 4 are children of 2 in 2nd row)
- Fourth row: 3 4 (children of 2 in 3rd row, none of the other elements in the third row have children)

My question is: When the construction ends, how many nodes will be assigned the integer $M$ and how many nodes will be assigned the integer $M - 1$?

Comment: When you say "my question", do you mean it is a question somebody wants _you_ to find an answer to? You can write down a recurrence for how many nodes get decorated with each number from $0$ to $M-1$; it ought to look very familiar. (Note that the height of each node in the tree has no significance).

Comment: @HenningMakholm: No it's a question that popped up from an unrelated context (not homework). The use of the phase "my question" was used just because I didn't know how to transition into asking the question. I'm very inexperienced in combinatorics, but thanks for your comment. The recurrence is indeed very familiar!